# how to add new index Highcharts column drilldown chart

Tags: jquery, highcharts

in the demo of high chart at:

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-drilldown

The values for chart is given as

```
Microsoft Internet Explorer 8.0 26.61%
Microsoft Internet Explorer 9.0 16.96%
Chrome 18.0 8.01%
Chrome 19.0 7.73%
Firefox 12  6.72%
etc...
```

in it there are 3 indexes, for example in the case of 'Chrome 18.0 8.01%'

Chrome is the first index,

18.0 is the second index,

8.01% is the 3rd index (the value with % sign).

i need to add another index before the value in %. that it looks like

```
Chrome 18.0 <my_value> 8.01%
```

and i need to use my_value in the chart also...

any idea ?

Comment: where do u want your <my_value> data to be? in tooltip?

Comment: ya.. correct. i need it in the tooltip....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well.. there are only two indexes. First one is name, for example:

`Microsoft Internet Explorer 8.0 - Tencent Traveler Edition`

and value:

`0.09%`

And are separated by `\t`. If you want another index, you need to add another delimiter `\t` with your value. Then in `parsed` callback add required stuff and do whatever you want to with values.